# How to Sort datagridview by column values which are of datetime type.?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem while sorting datagridview by column2 (name of the column i used )

i used datetime type values in the column and now i want to sort the grid ( named as conv_msg_grid) by using following command

```
conv_msg_grid.Sort(Column2, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

but it is giving an error " Object must be of type String."

what is wrong in it???

please help me out.....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have inconsistent datatypes in your table. Your first item(s) are of type string, but some of them are of type date. So when you try to sort and you hit something which isn't a string this error occurs.

To solve it you have two options.

1. Before sorting turn everything into datetime (or string) values. (This is the better choice if the user is allowed to add dates)
2. When inserting data into the DatagridView you make sure that all the values are of DateTime (or string). (This is the better choice if the user can't type in dates)

To do the (or string) option simply remove convert.ToDateTime and do ToString on value.

```
Dim Column2 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(0)
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    r.Cells(Column2.Index).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Cells(Column2.Index).Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

conv_msg_grid.Sort(conv_msg_grid.columns(2), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

Kalunche